# Writing more than one String to a file without deleting the first one. I am making favorites for a browser

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple browser for school and I am trying to make the favorites. This code here adds a favorite to a file(so I can keep it after the app is closed) and displays it in the TextView. My problem is that it can only save one. If i add the second one, the first one is replaced. I thought i could add them in an array or arrayList(or anything that works, i am open to suggestions), but i can't succeed. Please try to be explicit because I am kind of a beginner. Thank you.

```
package com.example.browser3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Favorite extends Activity {
EditText etName;
EditText etAdress;
Button bAdd;
TextView tvDisplay;




protected void onResume() {
readFile("favorite.txt", tvDisplay);
super.onResume();
}

public void writeFile(String fileName, EditText v, EditText x){

try {
    OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName,0));
    out.write(v.getText().toString()+ x.getText().toString());

    out.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public void readFile(String fileName, TextView w){
    try {
    InputStream in=openFileInput(fileName);
    if(in!=null){
        InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader buffreader= new BufferedReader(reader);

        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
        String str;
        while((str=buffreader.readLine())!=null){
            builder.append(str+ "\n");
        }
        in.close();
        w.setText(builder.toString());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.favorite);


etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
etAdress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdress);
bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
tvDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        writeFile("favorite.txt",etName, etAdress);
        readFile("favorite.txt", tvDisplay);
    }

});

}
}
```

Comment: what you need to do is read first the file then append the new "item"

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Comment: read this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,int)

Comment: If you are expecting to read lines of text, should you not be writing lines of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to open the file in append mode.Try this

```
try(BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt", true))) {
    out.write(v.getText().toString()+ x.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try opening your file in append mode. The constant is `MODE_APPEND`

```
OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_APPEND));
```

instead of 0